# Python + Urwid: columnized ListBox?

Tags: python, urwid

In my app I've got a ListBox containing very long list of short items. I would like to present as much items as possible per page for this I would like ListBox to show more than one column.

I've looked through documentation and didn't find anything describing a combination of ListBox and Columns containers. Is that possible to do? Or am I going wrong way?

Comment: You need a ListBox with multiple columns OR? Could you please illustrate what you want?

Comment: I need a ListBox displaying child items in multiple columns. Not ListBox with multiple columns. Illustrate how?

Comment: Illustrate through an image may be.

Comment: http://imgur.com/zAGUyYB - this is done with urwid.GridFlow. I want pretty much the same behavior, but scrollable.

Comment: You need to use Columns Class, with SimpleFocusListWalker. This will solve your needs.

Comment: I'm not following. SimpleFocusListWalker is a subclass of list, not Widget. How do I put them together?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
text1 = urwid.Text("text1", 'center')
text2 = urwid.Text("text2", 'center')
text3 = urwid.Text("text3", 'center')

childs = urwid.Columns([('fixed', 10, text1), ('fixed', 10, text2), ('fixed', 10, text3)], )

menuList = urwid.SimpleListWalker([childs])

lb = urwid.ListBox(menuList)
```

Comment: no focus, no navigation, definitely not what i need.

Comment: The above code sample is just to give you an idea to solve your problem.

Comment: it looks like urwid.GridFlow does everything I need, but my item widget is the actual problem: https://gist.github.com/8840770 - if i replace CmdWidget with urwid.Button everything works as expected. any ideas whats wrong here?

Comment: I just checked your code. Its running in front of me. Please tell what behavior you want?

Comment: resize the window so not all items are visible, press down key and get to the bottom -> nothing happens. i want it to make sure focused item is always visible.

Comment: Problem resolved :) See code of CmdWidget and FocusNoCursor in https://github.com/naquad/QuickRun/blob/master/qr.py

Comment: Excellent. Great News.